# Aerospike Java client handling multiple concurrect requests

Tags: java, multithreading, aerospike

I have a system where multiple clients make REST calls to my server, where I look up data in Aerospike and return them after some processing. I am using the **same instance** of Aerospike Java client to handle all the clients.

I am not able to find in the documentation whether  `client.get()` is a blocking operation or not. Should I create multiple thread-local instances of Aerospike clients to handle these requests?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about the thread safety of `AerospikeClient`, then the answer is that you can use a single client. Quoting the [documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.html):

> This client is thread-safe. One client instance should be used per cluster. Multiple threads should share this cluster instance.